# Must compact sets be contained in the topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can a set be compact but not be in the topology itself? For example, if $S$ is compact in a topological space $X$, must $S$ be in the topology $X$? Or does $S$ merely have to be covered by (finitely many) sets that are in the topology of $X$?

Comment: In the real line with usual topology no non-empty compact set belongs to the topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, compact sets do not belong to the topology, since usually they are not open. For instance, the only compact subset of $\Bbb R$ (with its usual topology) which belongs to the topology is the empty set.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sets in the topology are the open sets. Compact sets **can** be open, but in general they are not. For example, every finite subset of $\Bbb R$ is compact, as are the middle-thirds Cantor set and the set $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, and the only open set in the lot of them is $\varnothing$.

Every subset of every space is covered by an open set in the space, because the space itself is an open set. What makes a set compact is not that it can be covered by finitely many open sets: it’s that it has the property that **every** open cover of it has a finite subcover.

Comment: Ah I see, so the set itself has practically nothing to do with the topology endowed on $X$?

Comment: @CBBAM: That’s much too strong a statement. For starters, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then every compact subset of $X$ is necessarily closed. Beyond that, the topology on $X$ determines the subspace topology on the subset, and it’s that subspace topology that determines whether the subset is compact or not.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now.

Comment: @CBBAM: You’re welcome.